# How to get number of UV Channels with LWJGL assimp

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, assimp

In the C++ version of Assimp, there is a `GetNumUVChannels()` function, but i can't find a similar function anywhere in the LWJGL version of Assimp. Is there a function that I haven't found or is it not yet ported? it there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the getting number is currently not provided for this special port. I guess the hard-coded Number is 4 in the native library.

Comment: so 4 is the max number of them, but can't get the actual count?